# How to query public group of a user?

Tags: apex, query, public-group

I want to check whether a user contains a certain public group. I have tried the following select statement

```
[SELECT id, Name FROM Group where RelatedId=: userInfo.getUserRoleId()
and DeveloperName  = *`<public group name>`* Limit 1]
```

But this does not return any record even though I have assigned the user into the public group.

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure but Try something like this --- Might help you out in some way

> Next we query the Group Member table for records where our user is
>   specifically assigned and  also include records where our role is
>   assigned.

```
List<String> allGroupIDs = new List<String>();
for (GroupMember gm : [SELECT Id, group.id, group.name, group.type FROM GroupMember where (UserOrGroupId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND group.type='Regular') OR (UserOrGroupId IN :roleRelatedGroupIds AND group.type='Regular')]{
allGroupIDs.add(gm.group.id);
}
```

Also go through this - Lengthy but nice one

[Click Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/how-to-access-all-the-public-groups-relatedto-an-user-in-apex)